# Working with Entity Framework client vs server evaluation changes

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following exceprt of my query.  I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 project with EF Core.

I read that the server vs client has changed, so how I used to perform the WHERE part in Core 2.1 (using variables from elsewhere in my code) doesn't seem to work anymore.

So as below I have changed (as per something I read) to use ToList() in each part, but now is it not hitting the database more (in my Core 2.1 I would of only had the ToList on the final part as per the code comment below).

So now for Core 3.1 I need to have a dynamic where in the initial "// Load data" part - how do I do a dynamic Where in the initial part, or is there a way, now the server vs client changes are in EF Core to work around that (note it is the final "// Search" part that fails in EF under Core 3.1 (prior to adding the ToList 's)

```
public List<KBEntryListVM> lstKBEntry;

// Load data
var q = await (from _k in _context.KBEntry
               join _kc in _context.KBCategory on _k.CategoryId equals _kc.Id
               into _kc2
               from _kc3 in _kc2.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new KBEntryListVM()
               {
                   Id = _k.Id,
                   DateCreated = DateTime.Parse(_k.DateCreated.ToString()),
                   CategoryId = _k.CategoryId,
                   CategoryTitle = _kc3.Title.ToString().Trim(),
                   Text = _k.Text.ToString().Trim(),
                   Title = _k.Title.ToString().Trim()
               }).ToListAsync();

// KBCategory
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) && Guid.TryParse(c.ToString().Trim(), out var newGuid))
{
    q = q.Where(w => w.CategoryId == Guid.Parse($"{c.ToString()}")).ToList();
}

// Search  
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
{
    q = q.Where(w => w.Title.ToLower().Contains($"{s.ToLower()}") || w.CategoryTitle.ToLower().Contains($"{s.ToLower()}") || w.Text.ToLower().Contains($"{s.ToLower()}")).ToList();
}

lstKBEntry = q;    //.ToList(); this would of been the only place in Core 2.1 I would of had ToList()
```

Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So as below I have changed (as per something I read) to use ToList() in each part

EF Core 3.x+ client evaluation exception message suggests to *either* (1)

> rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

*or* (2)

> switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

So you are taking the option (2) which is easier, but you should try utilizing the option (1) which is harder, but better from performance perspective and the main reason implicit client evaluation have been removed by EFC 3.0. Option (2) should be your last resort only in case there is no way to apply option (1).

The exception message also contains the failed expression. Unfortunately it is not the exact part, but the whole expression (the whole `Where` predicate for instance), so you need to analyze it, find the failing part(s) and try to replace them with translatable constructs.

One of the general rules for simple data expressions is to avoid explicit conversions (`ToString()`, `Parse`). Store dates and numbers in database as such rather than strings, or utilize [value conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) when using old existing database and aren't allowed to change it.

In this particular query, the unsupported (non translatable) construct most likely are `ToString()` calls of `string` type properties (e.g. `Title`, `Text`). EF Core still supports implicit client evaluation of the **final** `Select`, so you won't notice it if there is no `Where` (or other) clause after that referencing such expressions. But as being said at the beginning, you should avoid them regardless - query the raw data and let the usages (UI) do the desired formatting.

Anyway, I can't tell exactly because you haven't show your model, but removing `ToString()` should make the query translatable, hence no need of intermediate `ToList()` or similar client materialization:

```cs
CategoryTitle = _kc3.Title.Trim(),
Text = _k.Text.Trim(),
Title = _k.Title.Trim()
```

You should probably also replace

```cs
DateCreated = DateTime.Parse(_k.DateCreated.ToString())
```

with just

```cs
DateCreated = _k.DateCreated
```

because it seems that `DateCreated` is already `DateTime`, so the double conversion through string doesn't make sense and would cause similar troubles. And even if the database type is string, still remove `Parse` / `ToString` and setup value converter which does that.

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer solved the problem.  It was, as you correctly pointed out, I made a schoolboy error of the ToString()'s in the initial part of the query.  Removing those and the DateTime.Parse made the original query work as expected without all the ToList()'s.  thank you again for identifying that.